# I am using TestNg for data driven framework,but data is not fetching from excel

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
  public class FlightVia {
  FirefoxDriver driver;
  Sheet s;

  @Test
  public void flight(String From) throws BiffException, IOException {
      driver.findElement(By.id("onewayDiv")).click();
      //FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Ravi/Desktop/kdf.xls");
      Workbook wb= Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Ravi/Desktop/kdf.xls"));
      s=wb.getSheet("Sheet1");

      String fromlist=s.getCell(2, 1).getContents();
      // WebElement fromdata= driver.findElement(By.name("sourceA"));
      Select fromdata=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("sourceA")));
      fromdata.selectByVisibleText(fromlist);
  }

 @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() throws InterruptedException {
      driver=new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get("http://in.via.com/");
      driver.manage().window().maximize();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      driver.findElement(By.name("op")).click();  
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
      driver.close(); 
  }
  }
```

when i am running this TestNg i am getting "SKIPPED: flight
`org.testng.TestNGException`: 
Method flight requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation." error

in excel sheet i am giving data as
    From    To
    Mumbai  Delhi
    Chennai Hyderabad

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the value for the parameter `From` in the flight method. You can use any of the method mentioned below:

- Use [@Parameters](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-testng-xml) annotation on the method and supply values in testng.xml file.
- Dataprovider (also mentioned by Cedric in his response) .. Documentation can be found at http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders
- Put [@Optional](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Optional.html) annotation on your parameter and supply default value.

Please check the TestNG document.

Hope it helps!

Comment: sir,if i have to pass value using dataprovider then why to use excel.

Comment: see if you have used a parameter in the method... you need to use either of the aforesaid method... and if you want to take data from excel then remove the argument from method flight!